# How can I solve the error "Cannot import name 'x' "?

Tags: python, keras, coreml

I'm trying to convert Keras to a Core ML model but I'm stuck when converting the Python file into a mlmodel.

I'm getting errors when importing submodules of 'coremltools'.

The error that I'm getting is: "python recog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recog.py", line 3, in 
    from coremltools import convert
ImportError: cannot import name 'convert'
"

I tried to import the submodules in a different way but nothing worked for me.

I hope anyone can help me!

You can see the Python code, in the sample below:

```
import coremltools
from coremltools import converters
from coremltools import convert

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('model.h5', input_names='data', image_input_names='data', is_bgr=True, output_names='species')
coreml_model.save('model.mlmodel')
```

Comment: There is no `convert` module, package or name in the `coremltools` package (See https://github.com/apple/coremltools/tree/v0.8/coremltools)

For importing the `keras` converter, write this to import the `keras` package:
`from coremltools.converters import keras`. Then use as `keras.convert(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name you are trying to import is in the module coremltools.

Answer (score 0):

In the file, coremtools.py double check if the name is same I.e. convert.
Check the location of the coremtools.py file, is it in the main folder of python where python.exe exists?